# Ionic Framework navigating from a view on one tab to a view on another tab

Tags: ios, mobile, web-applications, frameworks, ionic-framework

I'm building a hybrid mobile application using the Ionic Framework. I'm using the tabs style app and I'm wondering if it's possible to route from a view within one tab to a view with another tab with the ability to hit the back button and go back to the view on the other tab.

I shouldn't really need to show any of my code here as this question is more of a logic question within the Ionic Framework. If you have any example code of this working within the framework please do share it though.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Ionic uses angular states, so you can do something like this in `www/js/app.js`:

```
  .state('tab.chats', {
      url: '/chats',
      views: {
        'tab-chats': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/tab-chats.html',
          controller: 'ChatsCtrl'
        }
      }
    })
```

To get into "chats" tab view you use the state: `$state.go('tab.chats');` in a controller with a function and then call the function in your button with `onClick().`